# Convertir un array jerárquico en un set de datos para jsTree

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jstree

Estoy tratando de crear una función que convierta los datos almacenados jerárquicamente en un array con el siguiente formato: **id**, **name**, **idType**, **members**, **idParent** a **text**, **children**.

El contenido del array:

```
[
{"id":"1", "idType": "1", "name": "FCB", "Members": [{"name": "Lionel"},{"name": "Pique"}], "idParent": ""},
{"id":"2", "idType": "2", "name": "Football", "Members": [{"name": "Pique"}], "idParent": "1"},
{"id":"3", "idType": "2", "name": "Basketball", "Members": [{"name": "Pique"}], "idParent": "1"},
{"id":"4", "idType": "3", "name": "UEFA 14", "Members": [{"name": "Test"}], "idParent": "2"},
{"id":"5", "idType": "3", "name": "UEFA 15", "Members": [{"name": "Carlos"}], "idParent": "2"},
{"id":"6", "idType": "3", "name": "NBA 15", "Members": [], "idParent": "3"}
]
```

Lo que necesito es crear dos grupos dentro de la clave **children**:

- Comprobar si el padre tiene miembros y si es así crear un objeto {text: "Member": children: Aquí irán los miembros del padre}
- Agrupar los hijos del padre en un objeto con un nombre basado en la clave idType.

El árbol tendría que ser así:

```js
var array_expected =
[{ "text" : "FCB", "children": [
   { "text" : "Members", "children":[{"text":"Lionel"}, {"text":"Pique"}]},
   {"text" : "Sports", "children": [
     {"text": "Football", "children": [{"text":"Members", "children":[{"text": "Pique"}]},{"text":"Categories", "children":[{"text": "UEFA 14", "children": [{"text": "Teams", "children": [{"text": "Team 1", "children": [{"text": "Members","children": [{"text": "Puyol"}, {"text": "Iniesta"}]}]}, {"text": "Team 2"}]}]}, {"text": "UEFA 15", "children":[{"text":"Members", "children": [{"text": "Xavi"}]}]}]}]},
     {"text": "Basketball", "children":[{"text":"Members", "children":[{"text": "Pique"}]},{"text":"Categories", "children":[{"text": "NBA 14"}, {"text": "NBA 15"}]}]}]},
      ] }
]

$(function() {
    $("#expected_jstree").jstree({
      'core' : {
       'themes': {
        'responsive': true
      },             
        'data' : array_expected        
      }      
    });   
    
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.9/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.9/jstree.min.js"></script>

<div id="expected_jstree"></div>
```

He probado haciendo esta función, pero no consigo agrupar en un objeto los hijos por el idTypo y tampoco aparecen los miembros en los elementos que no tiene hijos. Por ejemplo **UEFA 15** tiene miembros pero no aparecen.

```js
var array = [
        {"id":"1", "idType": "1", "name": "FCB", "Members": [{"name": "Lionel"},{"name": "Pique"}], "idParent": ""},
        {"id":"2", "idType": "2", "name": "Football", "Members": [{"name": "Pique"}], "idParent": "1"},
        {"id":"3", "idType": "2", "name": "Basketball", "Members": [{"name": "Pique"}], "idParent": "1"},
        {"id":"4", "idType": "3", "name": "UEFA 14", "Members": [{"name": "Test"}], "idParent": "2"},
        {"id":"5", "idType": "3", "name": "UEFA 15", "Members": [{"name": "Carlos"}], "idParent": "2"},
        {"id":"6", "idType": "3", "name": "NBA 15", "Members": [], "idParent": "3"},
        {"id":"7", "idType": "4", "name": "Team 1", "Members": [{"name": "Lionel"},{"name": "Pique"}], "idParent": "4"},
        {"id":"8", "idType": "4", "name": "Team 2", "Members": [{"name": "Lionel"}], "idParent": "4"},
        ]

function create_jstree(array){
    var parent = [], children = {};
    
    for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; ++i) {
      var item = array[i],
      idParent = item.idParent,
      target = !idParent ? parent : (children[idParent] || (children[idParent] = []));
      
      target.push({ text: item.name, id: item.id, idParent: item.idParent, Members: item.Members, idType: item.idType});
    }
    
    var find_child = function(parent) {
      if(children[parent.id]) {
        
        if(parent.Members.length >= 1){
          var members = [];
          for(var i = 0; i < parent.Members.length; i++){
            members.push({text: parent.Members[i].name})
          }
          children[parent.id].splice(0, 0, {text: "Members", children: members});
        }
        
        parent.children = children[parent.id];
        
        for (var i = 0, len = parent.children.length; i < len; ++i) {
          find_child(parent.children[i]);
        }
      }
    };
    
    for (var y = 0, leng = parent.length; y < leng; ++y) {
      find_child(parent[y]);
    }
    return parent;
  }
  
  $(function() {
        $("#jstree_try").jstree({
          'core' : {
           'themes': {
            'responsive': true
          },             
            'data' : create_jstree(array)        
          }      
        });   
        
      });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.9/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.9/jstree.min.js"></script>

<div id="jstree_try"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las propiedades `children` y `parent` son imcompatibles. Si usas `children`, no hay que usar `parent`, y si se usa `parent` no hay que usar `children`.

- https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/

El árbol de `parent` necesita al menos estas 3 propiedades:

```
{
  id          : "string" // required
  parent      : "string" // required
  text        : "string" // node text
}
```

Hago una reconstrucción del árbol. El `parent` depende del `id`:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 Nivel    id parent   
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |                      
+ FCB   |   |   |   |   |   |   |           1 23456789 
    + Members   |   |   |   |   |           2 1      | 
    |   + Lionel|   |   |   |   |           3  2     | 
    |   + Pique |   |   |   |   |           4  2     | 
    + Sports|   |   |   |   |   |           5 1      | 
        + Football  |   |   |   |           6  5     | 
        |   + Members   |   |   |           7   6    | 
        |   |   + Pique |   |   |           8    7   | 
        |   + Categories|   |   |           9   6    | 
        |   |   + UEFA 14   |   |          10    9   | 
        |   |   |   + Teams |   |          11    10  | 
        |   |   |   |   + Team 1|          12     11 | 
        |   |   |   |   |   + Members      13      12| 
        |   |   |   |   |   |   + Puyol    14       13 
        |   |   |   |   |   |   + Iniesta  15       13 
        |   |   |   |   + Team 2           16     11   
        |   |   + UEFA 15                  17    9     
        |   |       + Members              18    17    
        |   |           + Xavi             19     18   
        + Basketball                       20  5       
            + Members                      21  20      
        |   |   + Pique                    22   21     
        |   + Categories                   23  20      
        |       + NBA 14                   24   23     
        |   |   + NBA 15                   25   23     
        |   |   |                             23456789 
  Nivel 3   4   5                          id parent
```

El array de `parent` lo reconstruyo de la siguiente manera:

```
var array = [
    {id: 1,parent:"#"  ,text:"FCB"}
    ,{id: 2,parent:1   ,text: "Members"}
    ,{id: 3,parent:2   ,text:  "Lionel"}
    ,{id: 4,parent:2   ,text:  "Pique"}
    ,{id: 5,parent:1   ,text: "Sports"}
    ,{id: 6,parent:5   ,text:  "Football"}
    ,{id: 7,parent:6   ,text:   "Members"}
    ,{id: 8,parent:7   ,text:    "Pique"}
    ,{id: 9,parent:6   ,text:   "Categories"}
    ,{id:10,parent:9   ,text:    "UEFA 14"}
    ,{id:11,parent:10  ,text:     "Teams"}
    ,{id:12,parent:11  ,text:      "Team 1"}
    ,{id:13,parent:12  ,text:       "Members"}
    ,{id:14,parent:13  ,text:        "Puyol"}
    ,{id:15,parent:13  ,text:        "Iniesta"}
    ,{id:16,parent:11  ,text:      "Team 2"}
    ,{id:17,parent:9   ,text:    "UEFA 15"}
    ,{id:18,parent:17  ,text:     "Members"}
    ,{id:19,parent:18  ,text:      "Xavi"}
    ,{id:20,parent:5   ,text:  "Basketball"}
    ,{id:21,parent:20  ,text:   "Members"}
    ,{id:22,parent:21  ,text:    "Pique"}
    ,{id:23,parent:20  ,text:   "Categories"}
    ,{id:24,parent:23  ,text:    "NBA 14"}
    ,{id:25,parent:23  ,text:    "NBA 15"}
]
```

El árbol de `children` necesita al menos estas 2 propiedades:

```
{
  text        : "string" // node text
  children    : []  // array of strings or objects
}
```

Reconstruyo manualmente el array con `children`:

```
var array = [
    {text:"FCB",children:[
        {text: "Members",children:[
             {text: "Lionel"}
            ,{text: "Pique"}
        ]},{text: "Sports",children:[
            {text: "Football",children:[
                {text: "Members",children:[
                    {text: "Pique"}
                ]},{text: "Categories",children:[
                    {text: "UEFA 14",children:[
                        {text: "Teams",children:[
                            {text: "Team 1",children:[
                                {text: "Members",children:[
                                    {text: "Puyol"}
                                    ,{text: "Iniesta"}]}]}
                            ,{text: "Team 2"}]}]}
                    ,{text: "UEFA 15",children:[
                        {text: "Members",children:[
                            {text: "Xavi"}]}]}]}]}
            ,{text: "Basketball",children:[
                {text: "Members",children:[
                    {text: "Pique"}]}
                ,{text: "Categories",children:[
                    {text: "NBA 14"}
                    ,{text: "NBA 15"}]}]}]}]}
]
```

#### Convirtiendo de `parent` a `children`:

La siguiente función recorre cada elemento y por cada elemento vuelve a recorrer el array para buscar el elemento padre y luego insertarlo como hijo.

```
function hacia_children(array){
    var salida = []
    var por_procesar = []
    for(var i in array){
        for(var j in array){
            if(array[i].parent==array[j].id){
                if( array[j].children==undefined ){
                    array[j].children = []
                }
                array[j].children.push( array[i] )
            }
        }
        if( array[i].parent=="#" ){
            salida.push( array[i] )
        }
        por_procesar.push(array[i])
    }
    for(var i in por_procesar){
        delete por_procesar[i].id
        delete por_procesar[i].parent
    }
    return salida
}
```

Por último elimina la propiedad `id` y la propiedad `parent`... De esta manera solamente queda `text` y `children`.

La propiedad `children` es un array de objetos. Si un padre no tiene tal propiedad, la agrega y va generando la lista de hijos.

El array que devuelve solo contendrá los elementos que su `parent` sea `"#"`, es decir, los de primer nivel.

Ejemplo de conversión de `parent` a `children` (ver en *Página completa*):

```js
var array = [
    {id: 1,parent:"#"  ,text:"FCB"}
    ,{id: 2,parent:1   ,text: "Members"}
    ,{id: 3,parent:2   ,text:  "Lionel"}
    ,{id: 4,parent:2   ,text:  "Pique"}
    ,{id: 5,parent:1   ,text: "Sports"}
    ,{id: 6,parent:5   ,text:  "Football"}
    ,{id: 7,parent:6   ,text:   "Members"}
    ,{id: 8,parent:7   ,text:    "Pique"}
    ,{id: 9,parent:6   ,text:   "Categories"}
    ,{id:10,parent:9   ,text:    "UEFA 14"}
    ,{id:11,parent:10  ,text:     "Teams"}
    ,{id:12,parent:11  ,text:      "Team 1"}
    ,{id:13,parent:12  ,text:       "Members"}
    ,{id:14,parent:13  ,text:        "Puyol"}
    ,{id:15,parent:13  ,text:        "Iniesta"}
    ,{id:16,parent:11  ,text:      "Team 2"}
    ,{id:17,parent:9   ,text:    "UEFA 15"}
    ,{id:18,parent:17  ,text:     "Members"}
    ,{id:19,parent:18  ,text:      "Xavi"}
    ,{id:20,parent:5   ,text:  "Basketball"}
    ,{id:21,parent:20  ,text:   "Members"}
    ,{id:22,parent:21  ,text:    "Pique"}
    ,{id:23,parent:20  ,text:   "Categories"}
    ,{id:24,parent:23  ,text:    "NBA 14"}
    ,{id:25,parent:23  ,text:    "NBA 15"}
]

function hacia_children(array){
    var salida = []
    var por_procesar = []
    for(var i in array){
        for(var j in array){
            if(array[i].parent==array[j].id){
                if( array[j].children==undefined ){
                    array[j].children = []
                }
                array[j].children.push( array[i] )
            }
        }
        if( array[i].parent=="#" ){
            salida.push( array[i] )
        }
        por_procesar.push(array[i])
    }
    for(var i in por_procesar){
        delete por_procesar[i].id
        delete por_procesar[i].parent
    }
    return salida
}

var array_children = hacia_children(array)

console.log( array_children )

$(function() {
    $("#jstree_try").jstree({
        "core" : {
            "themes": {
                "responsive": true
            },
            "data" : array_children
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.9/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.9/jstree.min.js"></script>

<div id="jstree_try"></div>
```

#### Convirtiendo de `children` a `parent`:

La siguiente función primero copia el `array` en `salida`, para no modificar el array original.

```
function hacia_parent(array){
    var salida = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array))
    var id = 0
    for(var i=0;i<salida.length;++i){
        salida[i].id = ++id
        if(salida[i].parent==null){
            salida[i].parent = "#"
        }
        if( salida[i].children && salida[i].children.length>0  ){
            for(var j in salida[i].children){
                salida[i].children[j].parent = salida[i].id
                salida.push(salida[i].children[j])
                salida[i].children[j]=null
            }
        }
        delete salida[i].children
    }
    return salida
}
```

Entonces va recorriendo el array `salida` agregando los parámetros `id` y `parent`.

Mientras lo recorre va moviendo el hijo del elemento actual al final del array, es decir, el `children` lo agrega al final y luego asigna al hijo como `null`.

Esto sirve para desempaquetar el array, aplanándolo de a poco. Al agregar el elemento al final, esto hará que sea parte del recorrido del array, y cuando no queden más hijos, dejará de recorrerlo, quedando todos los elementos en el primer nivel.

Muestro el proceso de cómo funciona de manera simplificada:

Primer paso:

- (índice del `for`) Primer elemento.

  - Segundo

    - Tercero

Segundo paso:

- Primer elemento.
- (índice del `for`) Segundo (hijo de primer elemento)

  - Tercero

Tercer paso:

- Primer elemento.
- Segundo (hijo de primer elemento)
- (índice del `for`) Tercero (hijo de Segundo)

Ejemplo de conversión de `children` a `parent` (ver en *Página completa*):

```js
var array = [
    {text:"FCB",children:[
        {text: "Members",children:[
             {text: "Lionel"}
            ,{text: "Pique"}
        ]},{text: "Sports",children:[
            {text: "Football",children:[
                {text: "Members",children:[
                    {text: "Pique"}
                ]},{text: "Categories",children:[
                    {text: "UEFA 14",children:[
                        {text: "Teams",children:[
                            {text: "Team 1",children:[
                                {text: "Members",children:[
                                    {text: "Puyol"}
                                    ,{text: "Iniesta"}]}]}
                            ,{text: "Team 2"}]}]}
                    ,{text: "UEFA 15",children:[
                        {text: "Members",children:[
                            {text: "Xavi"}]}]}]}]}
            ,{text: "Basketball",children:[
                {text: "Members",children:[
                    {text: "Pique"}]}
                ,{text: "Categories",children:[
                    {text: "NBA 14"}
                    ,{text: "NBA 15"}]}]}]}]}
]

function hacia_parent(array){
    var salida = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array))
    var id = 0
    for(var i=0;i<salida.length;++i){
        salida[i].id = ++id
        if(salida[i].parent==null){
            salida[i].parent = "#"
        }
        if( salida[i].children && salida[i].children.length>0  ){
            for(var j in salida[i].children){
                salida[i].children[j].parent = salida[i].id
                salida.push(salida[i].children[j])
                salida[i].children[j]=null
            }
        }
        delete salida[i].children
    }
    return salida
}

var array_parent = hacia_parent(array)

console.log( array_parent.map(x=>JSON.stringify(x)) )

$(function() {
    $("#jstree_try").jstree({
        "core" : {
            "themes": {
                "responsive": true
            },
            "data" : array_parent
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.9/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.9/jstree.min.js"></script>

<div id="jstree_try"></div>
```

#### Convirtiendo el array original

Para este array, es necesario que `Members`, se tome como hijo del elemento actual, y luego los elementos del array de `Member` serán hijos de `Member`.

```
{"id":"1", "idType": "1", "name": "FCB", "Members": [{"name": "Lionel"},{"name": "Pique"}], "idParent": ""},
{"id":"2", "idType": "2", "name": "Football", "Members": [{"name": "Pique"}], "idParent": "1"},
{"id":"3", "idType": "2", "name": "Basketball", "Members": [{"name": "Pique"}], "idParent": "1"},
{"id":"4", "idType": "3", "name": "UEFA 14", "Members": [{"name": "Test"}], "idParent": "2"},
{"id":"5", "idType": "3", "name": "UEFA 15", "Members": [{"name": "Carlos"}], "idParent": "2"},
{"id":"6", "idType": "3", "name": "NBA 15", "Members": [], "idParent": "3"},
{"id":"7", "idType": "4", "name": "Team 1", "Members": [{"name": "Lionel"},{"name": "Pique"}], "idParent": "4"},
{"id":"8", "idType": "4", "name": "Team 2", "Members": [{"name": "Lionel"}], "idParent": "4"},
```

Tomamos como ejemplo el elemento que tiene `id` con valor *7*. Originalmente es como lo siguiente:

```
{"id":"7", "idType": "4", "name": "Team 1", "Members": [{"name": "Lionel"},{"name": "Pique"}], "idParent": "4"},
```

Luego `Members` pasa como hijo, es decir, su `idParent` será el `id`, que es *7*. Se le agrega la propiedad `children`, que luego será quitada.

```
{"id":"7", "idType": "4", "name": "Team 1", "idParent": "4"},
...
{"id":"4", "idType": "2", "name": "Members", children: [{"name": "Lionel"},{"name": "Pique"}], "idParent": "7"},
```

Es momento de quitar `valores`, pasando todos sus elementos al final del array, que en este caso son dos. Estos elementos serán hijos de `Members`, es decir, su `idParent` es el mismo que el `id` de `Members`.

```
{"id":"7", "idType": "4", "name": "Team 1", "idParent": "1"},
...
{"id":"9", "idType": ..., "name": "Members", , "idParent": "7"},
...
{"id": ..., "idType": ..., "name": "Lionel", "idParent": "9"},
{"id": ..., "idType": ..., "name": "Pique", "idParent": "9"}
```

Siguiendo esta lógica, se puede programar la función que convierte el formato original del array al formato de *jsTree*.

Aquí además cambio los parámetros `idParent` por `parent` y `name` por `text`, y al `id` lo calculo mediante el `id` del último elemento del array.

```
function formatear_jsTree(array){
    var salida = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array))
    for(var i=0;i<salida.length;++i){

        salida[i].parent = salida[i].idParent||salida[i].parent||"#"
        salida[i].text = salida[i].name||salida[i].text

        delete salida[i].idParent
        delete salida[i].name

        var tipos = [
            ["2","Sports"]
            ,["3","Categories"]
            ,["4","Teams"]
        ]

        for(var j in tipos){
            if( salida[i].idType == tipos[j][0] ){
                var buscar_padre = x=>{
                    return x.parent==salida[i].parent
                        && x.text == tipos[j][1]
                }
                if( !salida.filter(buscar_padre).length ){
                    var elemento_nuevo = {
                        id: ((+salida[salida.length-1].id)+1).toString()
                        , text: tipos[j][1]
                        , parent: salida[i].parent
                    }
                    salida[i].parent = elemento_nuevo.id
                    salida.push(elemento_nuevo)
                }else{
                    var padre = salida.filter(buscar_padre)[0]
                    if(padre){
                    salida[i].parent = padre.id
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if( salida[i].Members ){
            var elemento_nuevo = {
                id: ((+salida[salida.length-1].id)+1).toString()
                , text: "Members"
                , children: salida[i].Members
                , parent: salida[i].id
            }
            delete salida[i].Members
            salida.push(elemento_nuevo)
        }
        if( salida[i].children ){
            for(var j in salida[i].children){
                var elemento_nuevo = {
                    id: ((+salida[salida.length-1].id)+1).toString()
                    , text: salida[i].children[j].name
                    , parent: salida[i].id
                }
                salida.push(elemento_nuevo)
            }
            delete salida[i].children
        }
        delete salida[i].idType
    }
    return salida
}
```

Esta función también genera las secciones a partir del `idType`. Si la sección no existe, la crea, y si existe la busca por el nombre y además coincidiendo con el `parent`.

```
x=>{
    return x.parent==salida[i].parent
        && x.text == tipos[j][1]
}
```

- Si el `idType` es *2*, genera la sección *Sports*.
- Si el `idType` es *3*, genera la sección *Categories*.
- Si el `idType` es *4*, genera la sección *Teams*.

La función `generar_id` sirve para asignar un `id` que no exista dentro del array. Lo que hace es obtener todos los `id` del array, luego obtiene el máximo de esa lista numérica y le suma *1*.

```
var generar_id = x=>1+Math.max( ...x.map(x=>+x.id) )
```

Nota: Ahora `Members` aparecerá abajo porque siempre se ordena por abecedario.

Código sobre el array original (ver en Página completa):

```js
var array = [
  {"id":"1", "idType": "1", "name": "FCB", "Members": [{"name": "Lionel"},{"name": "Pique"}], "idParent": ""},
  {"id":"2", "idType": "2", "name": "Football", "Members": [{"name": "Pique"}], "idParent": "1"},
  {"id":"3", "idType": "2", "name": "Basketball", "Members": [{"name": "Pique"}], "idParent": "1"},
  {"id":"4", "idType": "3", "name": "UEFA 14", "Members": [{"name": "Test"}], "idParent": "2"},
  {"id":"5", "idType": "3", "name": "UEFA 15", "Members": [{"name": "Carlos"}], "idParent": "2"},
  {"id":"6", "idType": "3", "name": "NBA 15", "Members": [], "idParent": "3"},
  {"id":"7", "idType": "4", "name": "Team 1", "Members": [{"name": "Lionel"},{"name": "Pique"}], "idParent": "4"},
  {"id":"8", "idType": "4", "name": "Team 2", "Members": [{"name": "Lionel"}], "idParent": "4"},
]

function formatear_jsTree(array){
  var salida = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array))
  for(var i=0;i<salida.length;++i){

    salida[i].parent = salida[i].idParent||salida[i].parent||"#"
    salida[i].text = salida[i].name||salida[i].text

    delete salida[i].idParent
    delete salida[i].name

    var tipos = [
      ["2","Sports"]
      ,["3","Categories"]
      ,["4","Teams"]
    ]

    var generar_id = x=>1+Math.max( ...x.map(x=>+x.id) )

    for(var j in tipos){
      if( salida[i].idType == tipos[j][0] ){
        var buscar_padre = x=>{
          return x.parent==salida[i].parent
            && x.text == tipos[j][1]
        }
        if( !salida.filter(buscar_padre).length ){
          var elemento_nuevo = {
            id: generar_id(salida)
            , text: tipos[j][1]
            , parent: salida[i].parent
          }
          salida[i].parent = elemento_nuevo.id
          salida.push(elemento_nuevo)
        }else{
          var padre = salida.filter(buscar_padre)[0]
          if(padre){
          salida[i].parent = padre.id
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if( salida[i].Members ){
      var elemento_nuevo = {
        id: generar_id(salida)
        , text: "Members"
        , children: salida[i].Members
        , parent: salida[i].id
      }
      delete salida[i].Members
      salida.push(elemento_nuevo)
    }
    if( salida[i].children ){
      for(var j in salida[i].children){
        var elemento_nuevo = {
          id: generar_id(salida)
          , text: salida[i].children[j].name
          , parent: salida[i].id
        }
        salida.push(elemento_nuevo)
      }
      delete salida[i].children
    }
    delete salida[i].idType
  }
  return salida
}

var array_formateado = formatear_jsTree(array)

console.log(array_formateado.map(x=>JSON.stringify(x)))

$(function() {
  $("#expected_jstree").jstree({
    "core" : {
      "themes": {
        "responsive": true
      },
      "data" : array_formateado
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.9/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.9/jstree.min.js"></script>

<div id="expected_jstree"></div>
```

Comment: No se si la respuesta es correcta o no ... ¡ Pero te lo has *currao* ! +1

Comment: @ArtEze  el problema esta en que yo tengo un array con el formato [id, idType, name, Members, idParent] y necesito convertirlo en alguno de los formatos que proporcionas más arriba, pero gracias por el tiempo que le dedicaste.

Comment: @ArtEze el formato lo obtengo de un organigrama que tengo en la página. El `idType` es un identificador que me he inventado para distinguir los diferentes niveles del organigrama.

Comment: @cplaiuu Edité la respuesta convirtiendo desde el array original en el formato inficado.

Comment: @ArtEze Muchas gracias por todo me salvaste la vida.

Comment: @ArtEze podrías mirar porque no funciona correctamente ? https://codepen.io/cplaiuu/pen/GRJGdXE Gracias.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105694/discussion-between-arteze-and-cplaiuu).